# Parameter passing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference

I am learning Angular and trying to dissect the following code:

**phone.js**

```
    angular
  .module('phone', [])
  .factory('phoneService', phoneService);

function phoneService() {
  var service = {
    getAll: getAll
  };

  function getAll() {
    phones = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Luke Skywalker',
      number: 111-222-333,

    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'R2D2',
      number: 111-222-444,
    },
  ]
    return phones;
  }

  return service;
}
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('app', ['phone'])
  .controller('AppController', AppController); 

function AppController ($scope, phoneService) {
    $scope.phones = phoneService.getAll();
    $scope.title = "Customer Phones";
  }
```

I am intrigued by the usage of `$scope` and `phoneService`. They are references to actual variables outside the AppController. `$scope` is the variable that AngularJS supplies and `phoneService` is a reference to the factory name in **phone.js**. I found that they must be named exactly the way they are, otherwise they won't be references to the actual ones with that names. Here is a link to [plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWPOjR7Zg2REu1Jym1E0).

I do not understand how this works behind the scenes. I tried to create a sample JavaScript to see if I can pass a reference to a global variable to a function and then access it inside the function. As expected it thinks the variable is undefined.

```
var i = {name: 'Bob'};
TestHello(Hello);

function Hello(i)
{
  document.writeln("name is --" + i.name);
}

function TestHello(K)
{
    K();
}
```

Link to test the above code at [js.do code](https://js.do/code/109021)

So, my question is what makes AngularJS code link the variables in an outside scope to the ones passed with the same names as the parameters?

Comment: `phoneService` is actually a reference to the name of the factory, not the function. You could have `.factory('SomeOtherFactoryName', myAwesomeFunction);` and you would then pass `function AppController($scope, SomeOtherFactoryName) {...}`

Comment: @Ronnie, thanks, I found that you are right. I'll update the question.

Comment: read the developer guide section on [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). That is what is going on here

Comment: And here's an excellent and easy-to-understand article about how dependency injection works: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/

Comment: @Dr.Cool, thanks for the link and has lot of what I was looking for!